# Disabling App Nap in Java

Tags: java, macos, osx-mavericks, energy

Our Java application makes background file transfer to a server. When the user wish to add a bunch of documents to the server and do something else with other applications, App Nap becomes active and slow down the window with the progress bar and the network transfert speed.

One solution is too opt out the entire application from App Nap, but it would be great if we could exclude some Java threads from being slowed down.

I am not sure how we could integrate the functionality of NSProcessInfo into Java...

Anybody have tried to do such thing from Java? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I dont have answer foor you but could you tell me how do you programmatically disabled AppNap. I tried using defaults command from terminal but it had no effect.

Comment: Sorry, it is a bit late. But, from the command line: http://cobbservations.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/disabling-app-nap-in-os-x-mavericks/

Comment: thanks, but I tried that and it had no effect for my Java application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following class [From here](https://github.com/shannah/Java-Objective-C-Bridge/blob/master/java/test/ca/weblite/objc/NSProcessInfoUtils.java) uses the [Java-Objective-C Bridge](https://github.com/shannah/Java-Objective-C-Bridge) to integrate NSProcessInfo functionality from Java.

```
import ca.weblite.objc.Client;
import ca.weblite.objc.Proxy;

/**
 * From https://github.com/shannah/Java-Objective-C-Bridge/blob/master/java/test/ca/weblite/objc/NSProcessInfoUtils.java
 */
public class NSProcessInfoUtils {

    private final static long NSActivityUserInitiated = (0x00FFFFFFL | (1L << 20));

    /**
     * To ensure Mac OS X doesn't slow down your app because of App Nap, call this method 
     * @param reason the reason for allowing the app to work at full speed
     * @return the activity id as a Proxy object
     */
    public static Proxy beginActivityWithOptions(String reason) {

        Client c = Client.getInstance();
        Proxy processInfo = c.sendProxy("NSProcessInfo", "processInfo");
        return processInfo.sendProxy("beginActivityWithOptions:reason:", NSActivityUserInitiated, reason);
    }

    /**
     * When the activity is finished, to re-enable app napping call this method 
     * @param activity previously returned by beginActivityWithOptions()
     */
    public static void endActivity(Proxy activity) {

        if (activity != null) {
            Client c = Client.getInstance();
            Proxy processInfo = c.sendProxy("NSProcessInfo", "processInfo");
            processInfo.send("endActivity:", activity);
        }
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the Java-objective-c bridge

Comment: Great! We are going to test this solution soon and accept your answer if it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of the referenced app nap post, found this via track back analytics. I am not familiar with Java development, however the link below may provide a method to access NSProcessInfo in the recommended manner. Interested to see what you find.

https://code.google.com/p/rococoa/